# Convert Java Spark DataFrame object to DenseMatrix

Tags: java, matrix, apache-spark, dataframe

Probably some simple question. Is it possible to convert an object of  [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) of Java Spark to the object of [DenseMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseMatrix.html) of Java Spark with some function?

Comment: `DenseMatrix` is a local data structure. Are you sure it is what you want? If so you can simply `flatMap`, `collect` and  pass result to `DenseMatrix` constructor.

Comment: yes, currently we use DenseMatrix. This is just temporar solution in our project. Thank you for your recommendation